# Libgdx - isButtonPressed isn't using the input button but rather a different button

Tags: java, libgdx

I have my input set to this currently:

```
if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Keys.D)) { x += 5; }
```

The `x` is set to the Circle's position:

```
shapeRenderer.circle(x,y,50);
```

I would like it so that every time I press D it will move right. However when I ran my code the circle only moves when I press the left mouse click button rather than D. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

For mouse buttons you would use

```
Gdx.input.isButtonPressed
```

For keyboard input you use

```
Gdx.input.isKeyPressed
```